# How to show views from assembly embedded resources (Mef)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, mef

In my project want to show some actions when they are plugged to the main asp.net mvc project with power of MEF and their partial views stored in the embedded assembly resources of their owner assembly. But I can't declare embedded views to razor view engine.

I receive `The view 'TestPlugin.Views.testplugin.Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.` error message.  I don't have any idea to "how to declare embedded views to razor view engine". Please help me solve this problem.

I have searched in stackoverflow.com and other sites but i can't found a good way to solve this problem.

I see sites like following addresses and other pages, but I cannot find what I need:

http://tiku.io/questions/53883/using-custom-virtualpathprovider-to-load-embedded-resource-partial-views

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553302/mvc-how-to-load-views-from-seperate-assembly

And more Addresses.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really have to do with MEF.

- Implement your own custom virtual path provider inheriting from [System.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider(v=vs.110).aspx).
- In the constructor, pass in the assemblies in which you want to look for views.
- Implement the `FileExists` and `GetFile` methods. Within these methods, look for the corresponding views through the [Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- Register your newly created virtual path provider in your `Global.asax` using the [HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.registervirtualpathprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Tips:

- Make sure the Views you want to load are really embedded resource.
- Debug your path provider and find out how to convert the requested path to the assembly file path. You will have to do a little bit of tweaking so the names will actually match. You can see how to list all embedded resource files [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.registervirtualpathprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).